# glibc: can't find memcpy dependencies

Tags: c, linux, glibc

Investigating glibc library for understanding of how memcpy function is implemented i found this piece of code:

```
#include <mach.h>

/* Threshold at which vm_copy is more efficient than well-optimized copying
   by words.  */
#define PAGE_COPY_THRESHOLD     (16384)

#define PAGE_SIZE       __vm_page_size
#define PAGE_COPY_FWD(dstp, srcp, nbytes_left, nbytes)                \
  ((nbytes_left) = ((nbytes) -                            \
            (__vm_copy (__mach_task_self (),                  \
                (vm_address_t) srcp, trunc_page (nbytes),     \
                (vm_address_t) dstp) == KERN_SUCCESS          \
             ? trunc_page (nbytes)                    \
             : 0)))
```

but i didn't find what is `__vm_copy`.

Could anyone help me to figure out what is `__vm_copy` and where it is implemented?

I cloned glibc repo and used grep utilite `grep -rnw . -e vm_copy` but haven't found anything.

Edited: Here is a [link](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/mach/pagecopy.h) of the code above

Comment: mach and linux are different OS

Comment: Seeing as how the only include is 'mach.h', looking at that file (https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.30.5/libsyscall/mach/mach/mach.h.auto.html) it appears it is from Apple.  Doing a google search of '__vm_copy' leads to this page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1585277-vm_copy.  Does this help?

Comment: memcpy on x64 with sse3 hardware is https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S

Comment: Thanks everybody i got it, i missed some part of source code code and turned out to be on these pease of cide that is related to mach not x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could anyone help me to figure out what is __vm_copy

It is a function implemented inside [Mach kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_(kernel)).

> and where it is implemented?

It is implemented here http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/vm/vm_user.c?v=MK84#L400 .